# Regex for HTTP User Agent

Tags: regex, agent

what Regex can be used to clear the HTTP User Agent of some of the information.
(I am actually interested in simplifying the user agent string in order to identify the device id for mobiles easier)

I would like to remove a string followed by a slash or a space and then digits and dots.

Slash before version

- Mozilla/5.0
- AppleWebKit/537.36
- Chrome/31.0.1650.59
- Safari/537.36

Space before version

- Android 4.4.2
- MSIE 10.0

Thanks,
Andrei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
 .+?[/\s][\d.]+
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regexr.com?37l4e

#### Discussion

You may notice that for this UA string there is more than 10 digits and dots. This is why I use `[\d.]+`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me a lot!
In the end I had to modify it because I realized that there is more information which is less standardized (like "Build/JWR66V", "Mac OS X 10_8_3', etc).

Again, thank you very much!