# User Agent Parsing in swift

Tags: swift, user-agent

Cobbling together bits I've come up with this but regex does not like pattern:
[from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569000/regex-for-http-user-agent)

```
struct UAHelpers {
    static func isValid(uaString: String) -> Bool {
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".+?[\/\s][\d.]+")
        return (regex.firstMatch(in: uaString, range: uaString.nsrange) != nil)
    }
}
```

[image: Invalid escape sequence in literal]

which looks ok to me - but no regex expert yet regex.com appears to like it? 
Also tried pattern: `\(([^(]*)\)` - no joy.

I'm trying to allow user (at own peril) to enter yet provide some parsing.

Comment: What are you looking to extract from a user agent string? They are [a complete mess](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/). Every browser is pretending they are something else

Comment: I do not know the genesis of spoofing another browser as I presume a webView or other browser would inherit a platform value. I'm just trying to provide the change ability and some parse verification - which I guess you could argue shouldn't be needed since whomever altering should know what they're doing and why.  I'm just trying to provide some parse validation. If the pattern is bogus please share a proper one, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent regex pattern `.+?[/\s][\d.]+` as a Swift String, backslashes `\` needs to be escaped.

(In Swift `String`, `/` has no need to be escaped.)

Try using `".+?[/\\s][\\d.]+"`.

Though, I'm not sure if this pattern really extracts what you expect.

Comment: duh; could'a sworn I'd escaped the whitespace and digit expression. I ended up with `".+?[/\\s][\\d.]+"` which tested at the regex.com site (less extra escaping) parsed some sample ok. I'm following what appears some convention to regex parse the strings intending all to match. I think that's the goal. As to why anyone would do / want that's beyond me. But if there's a better way, please chime in, thank you.